# Loading more posts in a different layout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, layout

I am having a problem in "load more" post button, I have set a layout for category page in my wordpress site, where I have a different grid layout and at the bottom a load more button. When I click the "load more" button it loads the post but in the same grid style. I want to change the style for newly loaded posts. I guess my question might be confusing. Let me try to explain with pictures.

[image]

As you can see, the first row is in different layout and after first row the other rows are in 3 column grid view.

Now whenever I click "load more" button, it loads the same layout. But I want the posts should be loaded in 3 column grid layout.

code below for layout!

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
<div class="container category-page">
    <div class="content-heading">
        <span><?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-listing">
    <div class="container category-page">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="content-post">
            <div class="row">
                <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'mtc_before_category_post', $index, $wp_query->post_count ); ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'mtc_category_post_column', 'col-12 col-md-4 mb-5 pb-4', $index); ?>">
                        <div id="posts" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                <div data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-image-side" style="position: relative; background: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>); background-size: cover; background-position: center">
                                    <?php if("video" == get_post_format()): 
                                        $custom = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_code', TRUE);
                                        ?>
                                    <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo trim($custom); ?>?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>

                            <div class="post-title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'mtc_category_post_excerpt', 'post-exerpt', $index); ?>">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-date post-date-fix-position">
                                <!-- <a href="<?php echo get_day_link(date('Y'),date('m'),date('j')); ?>"> --><?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?><!-- </a> -->

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php do_action( 'mtc_after_category_post', $index, $wp_query->post_count); ?>
                    <?php $index++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php if($index >= 8): ?>
    <div class="row load-more-btn" style="padding: 40px 0">
        <?php if(show_posts_nav()): ?>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <!-- <input type="button" id="load_posts" class="ar-bottom-link-tabs btn btn-primary btn-lg custom-btn" value="LOAD MORE ARTICLES" style="padding: 15px 30px;"> -->
            <button id="loadMore" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg custom-btn"><?php next_posts_link( 'LOAD MORE ARTICLES' ); ?></button>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and javascript for loading more posts.

```
jQuery('#loadMore a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).text() == "No more posts") return;
        $(this).text('LOADING MORE ARTICLES...');
        $(this).addClass("loader");
        $(this).addClass("loader-btn");
        var that = this;
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        $.get(link, function(data) {
            var cat = $('<div></div>').html(data).find(".post-listing");

            jQuery('.post-listing').append($(cat).html());
            var newLink = $('<div></div>').html(data).find("#loadMore");

            var newerLink = $('<div></div>').html(data).find("#loadMore a").attr('href');

            if($(newLink).html()){
                console.log("entered")
                $(that).removeClass("loader");
                $(that).removeClass("loader-btn");
                $(that).attr('href',newerLink);
                $(that).text("LOAD MORE ARTICLES");

            }else{
                jQuery('#loadMore').html("<a href='#'>No more posts</a>");

            }

        });
    });
```

I have looking for solution for so long, anyone can please guide me through this!

Thanks..

Comment: Hello, this code looks a little bit messed up, however... In the AJAX call, add a class to the div you just created. `var cat = $('<div></div>').addClass('ajax-posts').html(data).find(".post-listing");`, then you can use that class on css to style the new loop. e.g `.ajax-posts .post-title {...}`

Comment: I know code is little mess but can you explain it little further what you are trying to say... I could not get it.

Comment: @CodeAlb ?? can you explain it a little further?

Comment: what is `index` variable for?

Comment: its for change grid layout.

Comment: so basically you can set the index value to a particular number then it will set a specific grid layout?

Comment: yes and when ever I load more post index is by default 0.. so the layout is starting from the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace following line with your first line

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

<?php $index = $paged > 1 ? 6 : 0; ?>
```

replace it with your

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
```

in your case your 6th `post` is starting with 3 column grid view and now whenever `wordpress` finds that if page is not first page it will assign the `$index` value 6 and your newly loaded posts will be in 3 column grid view.

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks.. got that!... :)